# DataGrid cells with large padding break row selection

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have set Padding to DataGrid cells as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Padding applies fine, but the problem is that when I want to select the row if I click the empty space of the cell, the row isn't being selected. I have to click the actual text in the cell if I want to select the row.

How can this be fixed? I want to select row by mouse click anywhere inside the cell, be it empty space or text.

For example here I have a padding of 50 (I won't actually use 50 padding, but I want to illustrate the problem clearly):
[image]

The row will be selected only if I click within the green box I want the row to be selected when I click anywhere in red box of any cell.

Comment: Set background  and check it

Comment: @AvinashReddy The setter in the style by itself won't affect anything unless he adds a TemplateBinding in the template to make use of the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set some Background. default value is `null`. elements with `null` background do not register clicks/selection/etc

```
<Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="50,2" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

most likely later you will want to add Trigger, which will change Background for selected cells, so it is better to create binding for Background:

```
<Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="50,2" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```